# redirect to URL on ajax success in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

On ajax sucess I need to redirect to a URL having parameter (in MVC). I need the parameter not be visible on URL ( as quesrystring).

```
var Module=new Object()
Module="data";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: '@Url.Action("AddRecord", "Add")',
    data: Module,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    error: function (data) {

    },
    success: function (data) {
     //redirect to another page having parameter. But parameter should not be visible on URL
    }
```

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page. Do not use ajax if you want to redirect - its pointless.

Comment: still you can use window.location but parameter value are visible, so you have to encrypt that value Or before that you have to make extra ajax call and save parameter value in "TempData" and access on window location call

Answer (score 1):

**Store Your Parameters In Session**

```
    success: function (data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("abc")',
                        data: { username: $("#txtlgusername").val(),password: $("#txtlgpassword").val() },
                        type: 'GET',
                        success:function(data){
                        window.open("http://localhost:9999/home/Demo");
                            }   
                        })
                      }
```

**Make Action To Store Session**

```
public string abc(string username, string password)
 {
    Session["a"] = username;
    Session["b"] = password;
    return "";
 }
```

Comment: On ajax method stored values in Tempdata. on method that will called after ajax success I fetched value from tempdata.